# Asp.net Core Federation ADFS and Web Application Proxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, adfs

I've a .net core mvc web application with ws federation authentication.
I setted up the ADFS server and I successfully authenticate through adfs metadataaddress and realm
Next step was to use a WAP server to secure ADFS. But I got in troubles.
What should be the metadataddress? If I put the wap address the authentication doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to secure the ADFS server by using WAP - need to create a Trust between the ADFS and WAP server. The WAP server should be placed in the DMZ network. Kindly go through the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/best-practices-securing-ad-fs) and check everything is in place in order to secure the ADFS server using WAP.

Kindly check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn383644(v=ws.11)) for configuring the WAP server for ADFS